# Program fails when I call a method from constant reference

Tags: c++

So, I have a token class:
Token.h

```
class Token {
    std::string name; // token name
    int frequency;//frequency
    Vector lines;//lines where the token is present

public:
    //explanations for the methods in the Token.cpp
    Token(std::string tokenname, int linenumber);
    virtual ~Token();
    const Vector getLines() const;
};
#endif /* TOKEN_H_ */
```

Token cpp

```
Token::Token(string tokenname, int linenumber) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    name = tokenname;
    frequency=1;
    lines.push_back(linenumber);
}
Token::~Token() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
std::string Token::getName() const{
    return name;
}
int Token::getFrequency() const{
    return frequency;
}
const Vector Token::getLines() const{
    const Vector vec = lines;
    return lines;
}
```

The program fails, when I pass it to the insert method of list class

```
class List {
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        Token data;
        Node* next;
        Node(const Token &dataItem, Node* nextptr);
        ~Node();

    };
    Node* first;
    int length;
public:
    List();
    virtual ~List();
    void insert(const Token &t);
};
```

List.cpp:

```
List::Node::Node(const Token &dataItem, Node* nextptr): data(dataItem), next(nextptr){
}
List::Node::~Node(){
cout<<"dead"<<endl;
}

List::List() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    length = 0;
    first = nullptr;
}

List::~List() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
    Node* temp = first;
    Node* newtmp;
               while(temp->next != nullptr){
                   newtmp = temp->next;
                   delete temp;
                   temp = newtmp;
               }
}
const int List::size(){
    return length;
}

void List::insert (const Token &t){

        Vector dammit = t.getLines();

}
```

I found out which line in the insert does it(Vector dammit = t.getLines()), so I leave it like that.
It gives me this error message:

> double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000c34040 ***

And here something from main file if you want to run:

```
int main() {
//  cout<<"tokens are here"<<endl;
//
    Token hit("aca", 1);
    Token hit2("ui", 2);
    Token hit1("111", 3);
    List list;
    list.insert(hit);
    list.insert(hit2);
    list.insert(hit1);
}
```

Vector class:

```
class Vector {

int* store;
int capacity;
int next_index;
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(int initial_size);
    Vector(const Vector &v);
    virtual ~Vector();
    void push_back(int item);
    int pop_back();
    const int size() const;
    void resize();
    void operator =(const Vector &v);
    int& operator[] (int k);
    const int& operator[] (int k) const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vector& v);

};
Vector::Vector() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    store = new int [1];
    capacity = 1;
    next_index = 0;
}

Vector::Vector(int initial_size){
    store = new int [initial_size];
    capacity = initial_size;
    next_index = 0;
}

Vector::Vector(const Vector &v){
    store = v.store;
    capacity = v.capacity;
    next_index = v.next_index;
}

Vector::~Vector() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
    delete[] store;
}
void Vector::resize(){
    std::cout<<"in resize"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<capacity<<std::endl;
    int length = capacity;
    capacity+=100;
    int* tempArray;
    tempArray = new int[capacity];
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        tempArray[i] = store[i];
    }
    if (length>1)
    delete[] store;
    std::cout<<"finish re4size"<<std::endl;
    store = tempArray;


}

void Vector::push_back(int item){
    if(next_index >= capacity)
        this->resize();
    store[next_index] =item;
    next_index++;
}

int Vector::pop_back(){
    next_index = next_index-1;
    int last = store[next_index];
    return last;
}

void Vector::operator =(const Vector &v){
    //delete[] store;
    store = v.store;
    capacity = v.capacity;
    next_index = v.next_index;
}
const int Vector::size() const{
    return next_index-1;
}
int& Vector::operator[] (int k){
    //assert((k<next_index)&(k>=0));
    return store[k];
}
const int& Vector::operator[] (int k) const{
    //assert((k<next_index)&(k>=0));
    return store[k];
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector& v)
{
    for(int i=0; i<=v.size(); i++){
       os <<  v[i]<< ' ';
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: How does this code make sense? You're copying an internal vector to a scoped variable that evaporates. Unless you have more code that you're not showing us I don't see what it's trying to accomplish. Also, what is Vector here?

Comment: In `while(temp->next != nullptr)`, what if `temp` itself is null? That is, what if `first` is null?

Comment: @Nawaz This is indeed a problem.

Comment: I added vector, that is a good point. And I need it there, because if token exists, I add one vector content to another, without adding a new node, all tokens are unique.

Comment: @Nawaz Yeah, but it doest solve the problem I am asking about:/ One problem at a time pls

Comment: @Ophelia: Yes, that is why I didn't post that as an answer, did I?

Comment: I don't understand why you need a custom Vector class. `std::vector<Node>` should be good enough with some logic attached to it for now.

Comment: @VermillionAzure Well, me neither, but this was in requirements:(

Comment: This feels like it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/... There are quite a few rudimentary errors.

Comment: @nonsensickle Code Review is for improving working code. Broken code is very much off-topic there!

Comment: I dont ask for code review, I am just interested why that one line causes error! Because token is a constant reference? When it is not, it all works just fine. People ask here to give enough code to reproduce it, so I gave it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector &v){
    store = v.store;
    capacity = v.capacity;
    next_index = v.next_index;
}
```

You now have two vectors pointing to the same `int* store;`

In

```
void Vector::operator =(const Vector &v){
    //delete[] store;
    store = v.store;
    capacity = v.capacity;
    next_index = v.next_index;
}
```

You do the same thing.

when you call

```
const Vector Token::getLines() const{
    const Vector vec = lines;
    return lines;
}
```

`vec = lines` uses the copy constructor. You now have vec and lines pointing to the same store.

You return a copy of lines, this will trigger the copy constructor again. A third object now points to store.

When the stack unrolls, locally defined `vec` is destroyed. `~Vector` `delete`s store. You now have two objects pointing to the same de-allocated store.

Kaboom! as soon as you try to do much of anything else with either of those Vectors. Looks like the destruction of the returned Vector hits first and causes the destructor to re-delete store.

You need to allocate storage for a new store and then copy the contents of source store into the new store in the = operator and the copy constructor.

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector &v){
    capacity = v.capacity;
    store=new int[capacity];
    for (size_t index; index < capacity; index++)
    {
        store[index] = v.store[index];
    }
    next_index = v.next_index;
}
```

and

```
Vector & Vector::operator =(const Vector &v){
    delete[] store;
    capacity = v.capacity;
    store=new int[capacity];
    for (size_t index; index < capacity; index++)
    {
        store[index] = v.store[index];
    }
    next_index = v.next_index;
}
```

`std::copy` can be used in place of the for loop in C++11. Hoary old `memcpy` can also be used, but only because store is a primitive data type.

And while I'm editing, thanks Jarod42, one more little tweak:

```
const Vector & Token::getLines() const{ //note the return of a reference. This avoids 
                                        // making a copy of lines unless the caller really 
                                        // wants a copy.
    // const Vector vec = lines; don't need to do this. lines is const-ified by the
    // const on the return type of the function
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: good point, that makes sense. c++ after java gives me so much pain:D thanks a lot

Comment: store = new int[v.capacity];
 store = v.store; 
you mean like this?

Comment: @Ophelia in your = operator you will want to `delete` store before you make a new one.

Comment: @Ophelia `delete store;` `store=new int[v.capacity];` and then `for (int index; index != v.capacity; index++) store[index] = v.store[index];`

Comment: In place of the for loop, you can use `std::array` in C++11 or, only because store is an array of a primitive type, you can use `memcpy(store, v.store, v.capacity*sizeof(store[0]);`

Comment: sound like a good idea, although, memcpy kills my program completly 0_o i hate to loop then, thanks

Comment: Yay, I think now it is all fixed, thank you, I can go to sleep now!!!! I will dream of java and garbage cleaner

Comment: One of my earlier comments isn't correct.std::array won't work here because of dynamic sizing, but std::copy will.

Comment: And if whoever is doing the bulk upvotes on my answers is reading this, please stop. It's a really good way to get turfed from the site.

Comment: @Jarod42 son of a gun. So it does. Should have realized the compiler guys would be smarter than construct vec and instantly overwrite with assign. Updating answer.

Answer (score 1):

This error has nothing to do with calling a method with constant reference, but rather the function `getLines()`. For example, should you take `hit1` and call the function `getLines()` directly, it will crash nonetheless. The issue is with how `Token` has a stack-allocated attribute `Vector`, which in turn has an `int *` attribute. This isn't necessarily an issue, but depending on how you implement those classes it can cause memory conflicts.

If you want to keep using your `getLine()` and can't use the `<vector>` libraries, you could change your `Token`'s `lines` attribute to a `Vector *` and change all other syntax accordingly. Also remember to initialize your pointer `lines` memory or else it will crash.

However, I'd prefer to use as less dynamic-allocated memory as possible, if unnecessary. And like another user said, before `while(temp->next != nullptr)` you should have a condition `if(temp != nullptr )`